# Is yum confused or is it me?

Tags: php, rpm, rpm-spec, rhel6

I am building and installing custom RPMs on Centos/RHEL 6. When deploying on containers and VMs everything works as expected, however, on the production box we have extra, internal repositories. `yum install my.rpm` leads to a conflict with `php70w-*`:

> Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64
>   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could
>   try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

The php version chosen should be the 5.3.3 because of the RPM's requirements. `php-gd` is listed in the `.spec` which enforces that:

```
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1 for package: php-gd-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64
```

The interesting thing is that if I install all `php-*` packages by hand (exactly as listed in the `.spec` file) and then install the package everything works. (This verifies that the conflict has nothing to do with the rest/non-php dependencies). Note that I have `AutoReqProv: no` in the spec...

Questions:

- I would assume that yum will choose php 5.3.3 because all dependencies are satisfied without conflicts... why isn't doing that?
- How can I prevent that behavior for `my.rpm` installation only?

The solutions I have considered are:

- Explicitly state version `<=5.4` in all php requirements. However, since  I don't know what makes yum pick version 7, I am not sure this will work. Also, I prefer to keep dependencies version-less if possible. Once all required php modules are available in php 7 or once our software changes and we drop `php-gd`, it would be nice to port to php 7 without changing all versions in specs.
- In the repository definition on the host I can exclude the package. I would like to avoid this - I control the RPM spec but the repositories are set by sysadmins (using puppet)
- Instruct puppet to install all php dependencies first and then deploy `my.rpm`. A solution I don't like because we are splitting the installation in two steps and two different systems: puppet and rpm.

Any help and/or ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`php70w-common` looks like a webtatic or atomic repo package.

Either way you need to determine what repo it belongs to, either to exclude selectively the repo at install time or to configure repository priorities.

You can easily find out with:

```
yum info php70w-common
```

I prefer the priorities approach, which is cleaner and more portable.

https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities